# Why the K_RETURN event doesn't activate when pressing enter?

Tags: python, python-3.x

While trying to create a little input window with the pygame module, I was able to create a little rectangle in which to introduce text. The idea was whenever I pressed the Enter key, in would print the text to the window but it doesn't... It doesn't even recognise the enter key when I press and instead, tries to write it.

```
import sys, pygame
from pygame.constants import KEYDOWN
import string

pygame.init()
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode([800,800])
base_font = pygame.font.Font(None, 32)
user_text = ' '

input_rect = pygame.Rect(200, 200, 140, 32)
color_selected = pygame.Color('lightskyblue3')
color_non_selected = pygame.Color(255, 255, 255)
color = color_non_selected

textbox_selected = False

text_rect = pygame.Rect(600, 200, 140, 32)

print_text = False

while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()

        if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            if input_rect.collidepoint(event.pos):
                textbox_selected = True
            else:
                textbox_selected = False

        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if textbox_selected == True:
                if event.key == pygame.K_BACKSPACE:
                    user_text = user_text[:-1]
                else:
                    user_text += event.unicode

                if event.key == pygame.K_RETURN:
                    if user_text[0] in string.ascii_letters:
                        print_text = True
                    else:
                        print_text = False



    screen.fill((0,0,0))

    # Code for selecting, unselecting the box. Also makes the text to not get out
    # from the box when typing too much

    if textbox_selected:
        color = color_selected
    else:
        color = color_non_selected

    pygame.draw.rect(screen, color, input_rect, 2)

    text_input = base_font.render(user_text, True, (255, 255, 255))
    screen.blit(text_input, (input_rect.x + 5, input_rect.y + 5))
  
    input_rect.w = max(250, text_input.get_width() + 15)
    #Code for checking if there is text and if so, print it.

    if print_text:
        text_showed = base_font.render(user_text, True, (255, 255, 255))
        screen.blit(text_showed, (text_rect.x, text_rect.y))
        print_text = False
    else: 
        pass


    pygame.display.flip()
    clock.tick(60)
```

Could someone help me, I can't seem to find my error :/.
I use python 3.8

Comment: You insert *any* typed keys other than a backspace into the entry field - this includes a lot of other keys than Return that aren't printable characters.  And you only print the string if its first character is a letter - but you initialize the string to a space, so this condition will not be true unless you type a backspace before anything else.

Comment: first you could use `print()` to see what you have in variables and which part of code is executed - it is called `"print debuging"` and it helps to see where can be problem.

Comment: I don't understand why you check `user_text[0]` - why not `len(user_text) > 0`. OR maybe you shouldn't check anything but simply do `if event.key == pygame.K_RETURN: print_text = True`. BTW: you set `user_text = ' '` at start so `user_text[0]` is always `space` and `space` is NOT in `ascii_letters`. Maybe at start you should set empty string `user_text = ''`

Comment: I see other problem - inside `if print_text:` you set again `print_text = False` so it displays text only in one loop but in next loop it remove it. And you have `clock.tick(60)` so you have 60 loops in one second - so one loop takes 1/60 second which is 16 milliseconds - so your text is displayed only 16 milliseconds and you simply can't see it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that inside `if print_text:` you set again `print_text = False` so this text is display only in one loop which takes `16 milliseconds` (because you have `clock.tick(60)` and `1/60 second = 16 millisecons`) and text is removed very fast and you don't see it.

You should do it in totally different way. You should use `print_text` for displayed text (which you should blit in all loops) and `RETURN` should copy text from `user_text` to `print_text`.

```
   if event.key == pygame.K_RETURN:
       print_text = user_text
```

of course you may skip it if `print_text` is empty

```
   if print_text:  # it checks if `print_text` is not empty
       text_showed = base_font.render(print_text, True, (255, 255, 255))
       screen.blit(text_showed, (text_rect.x, text_rect.y))
```

but don't set `print_text` again to old value.

---

**BTW:**

You could use `if/elif/else` when you check KEY and this way you could skip `RETURN` from displayed string.

```
                allowed_keys = string.ascii_letters  # only text
                #allowed_keys = string.digits         # only integer number
                #allowed_keys = "01"                  # only binary number
                #allowed_keys = None                  # all keys allowed


                if event.key == pygame.K_BACKSPACE:
                    user_text = user_text[:-1]
                elif event.key == pygame.K_RETURN:
                    print_text = user_text
                else:
                    # filter keys
                    if (allowed_keys is None) or (event.unicode in allowed_keys):
                        user_text += event.unicode
```

---

Full working code

```py
import sys     # PEP8: every import in new line
import string  # PEP8: standard modules before other modules
import pygame
#from pygame.constants import KEYDOWN  # you don't need it because you use `pygame.KEYDOWN`

pygame.init()
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode([800,800])
base_font = pygame.font.Font(None, 32)
user_text = ''  # text in input widget

input_rect = pygame.Rect(200, 200, 140, 32)
color_selected = pygame.Color('lightskyblue3')
color_non_selected = pygame.Color(255, 255, 255)
color = color_non_selected

textbox_selected = False

text_rect = pygame.Rect(600, 200, 140, 32)

print_text = ''  # displayed text

allowed_keys = string.ascii_letters  # only text
#allowed_keys = string.digits         # only integer number
#allowed_keys = "01"                  # only binary number
#allowed_keys = None                  # all keys allowed

while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()

        if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            if input_rect.collidepoint(event.pos):
                textbox_selected = True
            else:
                textbox_selected = False

        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if textbox_selected == True:
                if event.key == pygame.K_BACKSPACE:
                    user_text = user_text[:-1]
                elif event.key == pygame.K_RETURN:
                    print_text = user_text
                else:
                    # filter other keys
                    if (allowed_keys is None) or (event.unicode in allowed_keys):
                        user_text += event.unicode

    screen.fill((0,0,0))

    # Code for selecting, unselecting the box. Also makes the text to not get out
    # from the box when typing too much

    if textbox_selected:
        color = color_selected
    else:
        color = color_non_selected

    pygame.draw.rect(screen, color, input_rect, 2)

    text_input = base_font.render(user_text, True, (255, 255, 255))
    screen.blit(text_input, (input_rect.x + 5, input_rect.y + 5))
  
    input_rect.w = max(250, text_input.get_width() + 15)
    #Code for checking if there is text and if so, print it.

    if print_text:   # it checks if `print_text` is not empty
        text_showed = base_font.render(print_text, True, (255, 255, 255))
        screen.blit(text_showed, (text_rect.x, text_rect.y))

    pygame.display.flip()
    clock.tick(60)
```

---

[PEP 8 -- Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)